# Codeigniter SQL query join on two different columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have the following tables:

Users:

```
+----+-------+-------+
| ID | fname | lname |
+----+-------+-------+
| 1  | Joe   | Doe   |
+----+-------+-------+
| 2  | Jane  | Doet  |
+----+-------+-------+
```

Products:

```
+----+------+------------+------------+
| ID | name | created_by | updated_by | //created_by and updated_by are user Ids
+----+------+------------+------------+
| 1  | some | 1          | 1          |
+----+------+------------+------------+
| 2  | some | 1          | 2          |
+----+------+------------+------------+
| 3  | some | 2          | 2          |
+----+------+------------+------------+
| 4  | some | 2          | 1          |
+----+------+------------+------------+
```

I want to create a query, which outputs the following table:

```
+--------------+------------+------------+
| Product Name | Created By | Updated By |
+--------------+------------+------------+
| Some         | Jane Doet  | Joe Doe    |
+--------------+------------+------------+
```

So far, I am using `Join` this way:

```
public function getAll() {
    $this->db->select('products.* , users.fname, users.lname');
    $this->db->from('products');
    $this->db->join('users', 'users.id = products.updated_by', 'left');
    $q = $this->db->get();
    return $q->result();
}
```

Which produces the following:

```
SELECT products.*, users.fname, users.lname 
FROM `products`
LEFT JOIN users ON users.id=products.updated_by
```

This works, and gets me the `updated_by` user information, but what if I want both the `created` and the `updated` user information, How can I make that query?

Comment: Add one more join that connect `created_by`

Comment: Can you please show me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am handicapped of `codeigniter` but if I understand your requirement correct, then following may be helpful.

```
public function getAll() {
  $selqry = 'p.* , u.fname as fname_ub, u.lname as lname_ub'  
  $selqry .= ', c.fname as fname_cb, c.lname as lname_cb'  

  $this->db->select( $selqry );
  $this->db->from('products as p');
  $this->db->join('users u', 'u.id = p.updated_by', 'left');

  $this->db->join('users c', 'c.id = p.created_by', 'left');

  $q = $this->db->get();

  return $q->result();
}
```

Above code should produce following SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
       p.*, u.fname as fname_ub, u.lname as lname_ub
       ,    c.fname as fname_cb, c.lname as lname_cb
FROM `products` as p
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id=p.updated_by
LEFT JOIN users c ON c.id=p.created_by
```

Comment: This is definitely helpful. I appreciate it. I tried the SQL statement and it works. I will try your CI code and implement it. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

yes this work prefect this very helpfully  for me

in my controller

```
public function out()
    {
          $selqry = 'p.* , u.items as REAL'  ;
          $selqry .= ', c.items as ITEM'  ;
          $this->db->select( $selqry );
          $this->db->from('outgoing as p');
          $this->db->join('financial_items u', 'u.id = p.item_id_real', 'left');
          $this->db->join('financial_items c', 'c.id = p.item_id', 'left');
          $query = $this->db->get();
          $data = $query->result();
          echo json_encode($data);

    }
```